# C# Remove all empty subdirectories

Tags: c#, .net, subdirectory

I have a task to clean up a large number of directories.  I want to start at a directory and delete any sub-directories (no matter how deep) that contain no files (files will never be deleted, only directories).  The starting directory will then be deleted if it contains no files or subdirectories.  I was hoping someone could point me to some existing code for this rather than having to reinvent the wheel.  I will be doing this using C#.

Comment: how about using powershell...?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Using C# Code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    processDirectory(@"c:\temp");
}

private static void processDirectory(string startLocation)
{
    foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(startLocation))
    {
        processDirectory(directory);
        if (Directory.GetFiles(directory).Length == 0 && 
            Directory.GetDirectories(directory).Length == 0)
        {
            Directory.Delete(directory, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A quicker way of writing your `if` statement could be `if (Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(directory).Length == 0)`

Comment: (!Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(directory).Any()）is better

Comment: this method worked for me but upon further reflection I had to do a double take at the fact that you're calling the method name inside of the method with that third line: `processDirectory(directory)`! Huh??

Comment: @user1985189: This is called a recursive function. see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_function

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCôté cool thanks for the answer! Can't believe I was never exposed to this in three courses worth of Java

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer That works too. But I'm not sure which one is the best for speed.

Comment: The Get* calls enumerates all entries before returning, The Enumerate calls yields items, so checking for Any makes it exit earlier (do less) work than collecting all entries - this could make a huge difference on directories with lots of items

Answer (score 57):

If you can target the .NET 4.0 you can use the new methods on the `Directory` class to enumerate the directories in order to not pay a performance penalty in listing every file in a directory when you just want to know if there is at least one.

The methods are:

- `Directory.EnumerateDirectories`
- `Directory.EnumerateFiles`
- `Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries`

A possible implementation using recursion:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DeleteEmptyDirs("Start");
}

static void DeleteEmptyDirs(string dir)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dir))
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "Starting directory is a null reference or an empty string", 
            "dir");

    try
    {
        foreach (var d in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir))
        {
            DeleteEmptyDirs(d);
        }

        var entries = Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(dir);

        if (!entries.Any())
        {
            try
            {
                Directory.Delete(dir);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException) { }
        }
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
}
```

You also mention that the directory tree could be very deep so it's possible you might get some exceptions if the path you are probing are too long.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately we don't use .Net 4.0.  I wish we could as I have about 20,000 folders to process.

Comment: Nice answer. Instead of `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(entries.FirstOrDefault()))`, you could also use `if ( ! entries.Any() )`, which is a bit cleaner IMHO.

Comment: @Danko Durbić, completely agree with you, I didn't notice the overload without parameters and was already asking myself why `Enumerable` didn't have something to quickly check for an empty `IEnumerable`. Thanks, I updated the answer.

Comment: This is the answer for large directories because GetDirectories is way to slow for decently sized directories. I would say that if you dont have .net 4.0 then you should use API calls from this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741306/c-sharp-get-file-names-and-last-write-times-for-large-directories

Answer (score 13):

Running the test on C:\Windows 1000 times on the 3 methods mentioned so far yielded this:

```
GetFiles+GetDirectories:630ms
GetFileSystemEntries:295ms
EnumerateFileSystemEntries.Any:71ms
```

Running it on an empty folder yielded this (1000 times again):

```
GetFiles+GetDirectories:131ms
GetFileSystemEntries:66ms
EnumerateFileSystemEntries.Any:64ms
```

So EnumerateFileSystemEntries is by far the best overall when you are checking for empty folders.

Comment: 131ms on an empty folder!?

Comment: 1000 times on an empty folder.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version that takes advantage of parallel execution to get it done faster in *some* cases:

```
public static void DeleteEmptySubdirectories(string parentDirectory){
  System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(parentDirectory), directory => {
    DeleteEmptySubdirectories(directory);
    if(!System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(directory).Any()) System.IO.Directory.Delete(directory, false);
  });   
}
```

Here's the same code in single threaded mode:

```
public static void DeleteEmptySubdirectoriesSingleThread(string parentDirectory){
  foreach(string directory in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(parentDirectory)){
    DeleteEmptySubdirectories(directory);
    if(!System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(directory).Any()) System.IO.Directory.Delete(directory, false);
  }
}
```

... and here's some sample code you could use to test results in your scenario:

```
var stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  stopWatch.Restart();
  DeleteEmptySubdirectories(rootPath);
  stopWatch.Stop();
  StatusOutputStream.WriteLine("Parallel: "+stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  stopWatch.Restart();
  DeleteEmptySubdirectoriesSingleThread(rootPath);
  stopWatch.Stop();
  StatusOutputStream.WriteLine("Single: "+stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

... and here're some results from my machine for a directory that is on a file share across a wide area network.  This share currently has only 16 subfolders and 2277 files.

```
Parallel: 1479
Single: 4724
Parallel: 1691
Single: 5603
Parallel: 1540
Single: 4959
Parallel: 1592
Single: 4792
Parallel: 1671
Single: 4849
Parallel: 1485
Single: 4389
```

Answer (score 3):

From here, [Powershell script to remove empty directories](http://guyellisrocks.com/powershell/powershell-script-to-remove-empty-directories/):

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Recurse

foreach($item in $items)
{
      if( $item.PSIsContainer )
      {
            $subitems = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $item.FullName
            if($subitems -eq $null)
            {
                  "Remove item: " + $item.FullName
                  Remove-Item $item.FullName
            }
            $subitems = $null
      }
}
```

**Note**: use at own risk!

Comment: Powershell is not an option, sorry.  Thanks though.

Comment: the topic is talking about c sharp

Comment: @shtse8: getting a task done is about using whatever is easy.

Answer (score 3):

If you rely on `DirectoryInfo.Delete` only deleting empty directories, you can write a succinct extension method

```
public static void DeleteEmptyDirs(this DirectoryInfo dir)
{
    foreach (DirectoryInfo d in dir.GetDirectories())
        d.DeleteEmptyDirs();

    try { dir.Delete(); }
    catch (IOException) {}
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) {}
}
```

Usage:

```
static void Main()
{
    new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp").DeleteEmptyDirs();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    private static void deleteEmptySubFolders(string ffd, bool deleteIfFileSizeZero=false)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(ffd);
    foreach (DirectoryInfo diSon in di.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    {
        FileInfo[] fis = diSon.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        if (fis == null || fis.Length < 1)
        {
            diSon.Delete(true);
        }
        else
        {
            if (deleteIfFileSizeZero)
            {
                long total = 0;
                foreach (FileInfo fi in fis)
                {
                    total = total + fi.Length;
                    if (total > 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (total == 0)
                {
                    diSon.Delete(true);
                    continue;
                }
            }

            deleteEmptySubFolders(diSon.FullName, deleteIfFileSizeZero);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Recursive scan of empty dirs. See example output bottom

string startDir = @"d:\root";

void Scan(string dir, bool stepBack)
    {
        //directory not empty
        if (Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(dir).Length > 0)
        {
            if (!stepBack)
            {
                foreach (string subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
                    Scan(subdir, false);
            } 
        }
        //directory empty so delete it.
        else
        {
            Directory.Delete(dir);
            string prevDir = dir.Substring(0, dir.LastIndexOf("\\"));
            if (startDir.Length <= prevDir.Length)
                Scan(prevDir, true);
        }
    }
//call like this
Scan(startDir, false);

/*EXAMPLE outputof d:\root with empty subfolders and one filled with files
   Scanning d:\root
   Scanning d:\root\folder1 (not empty)
   Scanning d:\root\folder1\folder1sub1 (not empty)
   Scanning d:\root\folder1\folder1sub1\folder2sub2 (deleted!)
   Scanning d:\root\folder1\folder1sub1 (deleted!)
   Scanning d:\root\folder1 (deleted)
   Scanning d:\root (not empty)
   Scanning d:\root\folder2 (not empty)
   Scanning d:\root\folder2\folder2sub1 (deleted)
   Scanning d:\root\folder2 (not empty)
   Scanning d:\root\folder2\notempty (not empty) */
```

Comment: This algoritm will delete all empty directories in a given start directory. When a directory is deleted, the previous directory will be re-scanned because it is possible that the previous directory is now empty.

Comment: That is not needed. You should think about the benefits of recursion and maybe slowly debug through the already provided answers.

Comment: True, but what is not recursive about this? I was a little to fast and so i made a small correction. See output example on what this code does. I think this is efficient.

Comment: If you would put the `foreach` above the `if` statement you wouldn't need the `stepBack` parameter which would make your code much easier to read (end your code would end up with the same result as the already given answers). Also you should use `Directory.Enumerate...()` instead of `Directory.Get...()`. Thus your answer doesn't provide anything new to the already given ones and makes it obsolete.

Comment: The reason i believe this parameter makes it more efficient (and that's my contribution although i could be wrong though :) ) is because - only a parent folder of a deleted folder will be re-scanned again, "without rescanning all the sub directories of the parent folder again" -
Try it yourself. check the output with and without the stepback parameter. You'll see that without it, folders are scanned multiple times.

Comment: Take João Angelo answer and there also each directory will be scanned only once (without using any parameters for the recursion).

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(myDir, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        {
            try
            {
                if (Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length == 0)
                    Directory.Delete(folder, true);
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var emptyDir in Directory.GetDirectories(root,"*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                  .Select(p=>new DirectoryInfo(p))
                                  .Where(p=>p.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count() == 0))
{
        
    if(emptyDir.Exists){emptyDir.Delete(true);}

    
}
```