# Delete all empty directories in specified path

Tags: c#

In my program, I create a long branching tree of directories.  When I'm done with certain files on the leaves of this tree, I delete them, but I end up with a lot of empty parent directories.  I'd like to delete these as well.  However, I can't just recursively delete all these parent directories, because some of them have children that I can't delete yet.

Example:
C:\MyProject\Project1\file1\file2\file3\file4\file5\document.txt

If I delete document.txt, I want to also delete all the other empty folders in the path. However, file 3 has something in it (besides file4), so I can't delete it or anything above it.  So in this case, file4 and file5 would be deleted.

Consider the root directory to be Project1.  I don't want to delete anything above that.

Has anyone written something to do this?

Basically, something I can call where I can specify the path I'm trying to remove from the tree (first arg below), along with the root of the tree (second arg).

```
DeleteEmptySubDirectoriesInPath("C:\MyProject\Project1\file1\file2\file3\file4\file5\",
"C:\MyProject\Project1");
```

Another way to look at it is the inverse of Directory.CreateDirectory.  This is the function I used to generate these long branches.  Now I need to remove them when I'm done without disturbing anything else.

Comment: Will this work?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2811654/2855568

Comment: @NielW Make sure you use the `EnumerateFileSystemEntries` suggestion in the comments of the question that @DeveloperGuo linked.

Comment: That's sort of the idea.  I actually looked there first.  The problem with that approach is it's top down, and will delete other empty directories that are not in the path I'm trying to delete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little bit of iteration would work:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\MyProject\Project1\file1\file2\file3\file4\");
var root = @"C:\MyProject\Project1"; // no trailing slash!
while (di.FullName != root 
       && !di.EnumerateFiles().Any() 
       && !di.EnumerateDirectories().Any())
{
    di.Delete();
    di = di.Parent;
}
```

Start from the directory of interest; as long as there are no files and you have not reached the "root", delete it and move to its parent directory. Repeat until done.

Comment: This is great, but it throws if there are any subfolders in the directory being deleted.  I added " && !di.EnumerateDirectories().Any()" to the while clause, and it works great.  I sugggest updating your answer so I can select it.

Comment: @NielW: Hm, I thought you would be always starting from a leaf directory. Sure, going to update.

Comment: I am, but some of the parents have other children.  When I say "the directory being deleted", I'm referring to your "di".

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't seem like it should be any more difficult than this:

- We delete the file
- Walk up the directory tree, deleting [empty] directories as we go until we get to the root.

Here's the code:

```
static void DeleteAndPrune(string path)
{
  FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
  fi.Delete();

  // the loop ends with the first non-empty directory, or the root.
  // - if the directoryInfo itself is null, the file was deleted *from* the root,
  //   so there's nothing to do.
  // - if the directoryInfo's parent is null, we've hit the root directory
  // Easy!      
  for ( DirectoryInfo di = fi.Directory ; di != null && di.Parent != null && !di.EnumerateFileSystemInfos().Any() ; di = di.Parent )
  {
    di.Delete() ;
  }

  return;
}
```

It's almost simpler if you want to just walk the entire tree and tidy it to remove empty directories. Just a simple recursive tree walk:

```
    static void Tidy( DirectoryInfo tree )
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo di in tree.EnumerateDirectories())
        {
            Tidy(di);
        }
        tree.Refresh();
        if (!tree.EnumerateFileSystemInfos().Any())
        {
            tree.Delete();
        }
        return;
    }
```

That can be done like so:

```
DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo( @"C:\MyProject\Project1" ) ;
Tidy(root) ;
```