# Read files off the disk based on LastWriteTime and file count

Tags: c#, file, datetime

I need to read files of the disk based on the two following conditions

1. Read files that are recent i.e. must be newer then a user supplied DateTime object
2. And since I am bulk processing these files. I have a limit of 100 files per bulk.

Therefore, I need to make sure that the last 100 files I have read are recent and whenever I need to get the next bulk of 100 file names, I must be able to start from 101st file given that DateTime factor must not be broken.

LINQ would be good to use!

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741306/c-sharp-get-file-names-and-last-write-times-for-large-directories may be this helps for u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what you need, with .NET 4.0 you can write something like this:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, searchPattern)
 .Select(path => new FileInfo(path))
 .Where(fileInfo => fileInfo.LastWriteTime >= date)
 .OrderBy(fileInfo => fileInfo.LastWriteTime)
 .Take(100);
```

If you're using a previous version of the framework you may use Directory.GetFiles() but you **MUST** check its performance because it reads the **FULL** list of directory entries.

Comment: You're right, to do not keep in memory the full file list then OrderBy clause should be moved after the Where clause! Thank you!